# Adjust the color of a shape based on its width! in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a graph. I want to adjust the color in the graph.
I want to set that if the value of `minimum width` of every shape is less than 5, then its color should be green!5. If the minimum width is 5< and <10, then the color should be green!50. I have thousands of this figures and this is really important for me. Do you have any solution for that? Thank you here is a simple of my code;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

%% setting shekl
\newcommand\hight{0.9}
\newcommand\val{50}
\newcommand\mycolor{green}

\newcommand\widthdirect{3} 
\newcommand\widthback{14}



\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
font=\sf \scriptsize,
>=LaTeX,
background/.style={rectangle, minimum height =\hight cm,minimum width=\widthback cm, rounded corners=4.4mm, fill=black!10, draw,thick,},
direct/.style={rectangle, minimum height =\hight cm, rounded corners=4.4mm, minimum width=\widthdirect cm, fill=green!10, draw,thick,},
]


\node [background] at (0,1){} ;
\node [direct] at (0,1){} ;


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should probably not define a new macro called `\color` because this is already defined by other mechanisms for color management.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the provided information it is hard to grasp exactly which approach suits your use case the best, but one way might be to define a command to do the logic to set the correct colour percentage. Of course, I am proposing something like this, because I see that you define some command containing a width that you hand over to `minimum width`. It would be a completely different story to go through an arbitrary number of drawn shapes in an arbitrary `tikzpicture`, deduce the minimum width of every drawn node and then set the colour as you wish.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\widthdirect{3}
\newcommand{\colPerc}[1]{%
    \ifnum#1<5
        5%
    \else
        \ifnum#1<10
            50%
        \else
            100%
        \fi
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[direct/.style={rectangle, minimum height=0.9cm,
                                       rounded corners=4.4mm, minimum width=\widthdirect cm,
                                       fill=green!\colPerc{\widthdirect}, draw,thick,}]
        \node [direct] at (0,1){} ;
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \renewcommand\widthdirect{8}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[direct/.style={rectangle, minimum height=0.9cm,
                                       rounded corners=4.4mm, minimum width=\widthdirect cm,
                                       fill=green!\colPerc{\widthdirect}, draw,thick,}]
        \node [direct] at (0,1){} ;
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \renewcommand\widthdirect{12}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[direct/.style={rectangle, minimum height=0.9cm,
                                       rounded corners=4.4mm, minimum width=\widthdirect cm,
                                       fill=green!\colPerc{\widthdirect}, draw,thick,}]
        \node [direct] at (0,1){} ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course, this is pretty basic and depending on your needs you might extract the TikZ style into a more refined, global one.

[image: fig]